# How to analyze python code *within python* to identify variable names, function calls etc

Tags: python, python-3.x, parsing

I am trying to analyze snippets of incomplete python code (from github diffs) and I want to parse whether a specific token is a element of the python language (e.g. "if" or "+" or "def"), if it is a function call (like "initialize()"), or if it is a variable name.

The code is provided as a string.

I already looked at the python tokenizer (https://docs.python.org/3/library/tokenize.html), which is helpful because it can differentiate comments, strings, names and operations. But this tool will identify "def" and "print" as NAME, just as it does with "my_function()" or "counter" or any other variable or function name.

I would like to differentiate between things that are parsed as variables and things that are parsed as functions.

I also had a look at eval and exec, but I don't want to execute my code, I just want to go through it token by token and find out what kind of python language element the token is.

Is there any way of doing this?

Comment: You can't distinguish `print` and `my_function`, because they really are just names. `def` is different, as it's a keyword.

Comment: I also looked at the AST module, but it seems like this won't work with incomplete snippets of code that do not form a complete, valid block of code?

Comment: Yes, and it won't let you map the output to tokens.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `keyword` module to distinguish between keywords and identifiers:

```
import keyword

def is_keyword(name):
    return name in keyword.kwlist
```

Builtins like `print` are identifiers like any other, you can override them etc. If you still want to treat them differently, you can check if a name is in the `builtins` module:

```
import builtins

def is_builtin(name):
    return name in builtins.__dict__
```

Comment: This is great and already helps me a lot! Thank you so much for your quick reply!